# connecting to amazon aws linux server by ssh on mac

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-ec2

I created a new keypair and downloaded it to my mac, then set up a new Amazon Linux AMI server with that keypair and my security group. Now I need to put the keypair .pem file that I downloaded in a .ssh file in my users folder?  I am unable to create a folder called ".ssh" however because of the name.

Where do I put the keypair on my mac? and what chmods or other commands are then needed to connect to the server from my linux bash? I know "ssh my public DNS" but what other permissions or anything else should I be aware of? Its a newbie question. Thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You'll want to put the keypair in {your home directory}/.ssh . If that folder doesn't exist, create it.  Once you put the keypair in there you have to change the permissions on the file so only your user can read it.
Launch the terminal and type

```
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/<your keypair file>
```

That limits access to the file, and then to limit access to the folder type

```
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
```

You have to limit the access because the OpenSSH protocol won't let you use a key that other's can view.

Then to log into your instance, from the terminal you would enter

`ssh -i <your home directory>/.ssh/<your keypair file> ec2-user@<ec2 hostname>`

Comment: I think you mean ~/.ssh instead of /.ssh

Comment: Thats part of the problem. I cant create a folder called ".ssh" because the period in the name is not allowed. How do I create that folder? Thanks for your above answer.

Comment: The period in front of the folder name only means that the folder is hidden. Go into your terminal and type ls -la ~ and you see all the folders in your home directory, including hidden folders.
If you don't see the folder, while still in the terminal type 
mkdir ~/. ssh

Comment: Based on an online AWS tutorial, users are asked to run chmod 400, which one should be done instead?
Tutorial link: http://railsconf2015-aws.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 67):

you can also create a file ~/.ssh/config
chmod it 644
then inside you can add something like this

```
host mybox-root
  Hostname [the IP or dns name]
  User root
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/[your keypair here]
```

then you can just do

$ ssh mybox-root

and you'll login easier.

Comment: Great answer. I would encourage everyone to follow this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java MindTerm to connect to your EC2 server in Macbook pro.  It works for me.  here are  the more details and step by step instruction.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openssh.com/ is the suggested one on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-connect-to-instance-linux.html#using-ssh-client (option 3)

Answer (score -1):

Someone was asking on Mac's an easy way to create the ~/.ssh folder would be by running command ssh-keygen, then use following setup ...

A.

```
macbook-air$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/sam/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/sam/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/sam/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

B. Then create:

```
touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

C. Fix the permissions:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

D. Copy AWS Key to that file:

```
cp AWS_key.text ~sam/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

#You would have saved this SSH key earlier when creating the EC2 instance

E. Then test the ssh to AWS Linux server - you will see this error:

```
ssh -i ./authorized_keys root@ec2-54-76-176-29.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".

F. Re-try that and it should work with allowed AWS user "ec2-user":

```
ssh -i ./authorized_keys ec2-user@ec2-54-76-176-29.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/
9 package(s) needed for security, out of 12 available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
```

Hope this helps, all the best.

Comment: This is incorrect. The ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file is for containing the public key of a user that is allowed to authenticate with the server it is on, not for connecting to external servers.