# Failure to authenticate SSH keys

Tags: ssh-keys

I'm in the process of setting up a virtual server via Amazon AWS.  I followed their tutorial regarding setting up a Linux based virtual server on OS X.  Everything goes well until I get to the .ssh pair key file.  I download AWS's key as a .pem file.  It saves as a .pem.txt file.  Which seems odd from what I'm reading.  So, I duplicate and change the extension to .pem only.
   Then I go to copy the file from downloads to the ~/.ssh folder and get no problems using `cp ~/Downloads/FileName.pem ~/.ssh.`  When I try to use chmod 400 to adjust the security parameters of the folder it returns "Not a directory".  When I try to authenticate it fails.  I suspect because it has something to do with the chmod 400 code line, but I'm not certain.  I also wanted to verify to make sure the file copied into the .ssh folder, but all of the suggestions online about unhiding the hidden folders on a Mac were a no-go.
   It is a Linux set up so the user name is the one listed in the tutorial (I already researched this problem).  I double check to see if there was a file .ssh and there seems to be.  When I type ssh in the terminal I do get feedback, so I'm assuming there is a file there.

Comment: run `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/<name of your file>.pem`

Comment: Note that ~/.ssh is a folder, it's not a file. Does that folder exist? Is your new pem file in that folder?

Comment: First of all file extenstion should be .pem not .pem.txt .Then you should copy that file to .ssh folder(its a directory not a file).Then you have to set permission to 400.

Comment: Bikash:  It returns no error on return, then I run the chmod 400 code and it tells me that it's not a directory.

Comment: @BikashPaul Bikash: when I hit the download button on AWS's pair key generator it generates a txt file and saves it to my downloads folder.  It is named MyPairKey.pem.txt.  I do copy the file to the folder (after changing the name to MyPairKey.pem) by using the terminal cp ~/Downloads/MyPairKey.pem ~/.ssh

Comment: @jarmod Jarmod: Sorry, I didn't use the correct terminology.  I can't see the .ssh folder (not file) in my home directory.  It doesn't show up.  However, if I type in ssh in the terminal and press return I get a list of details.  I have been unable to unhide the folders, so I can't visually verify that the folder exists or that the file KeyName.pem is in the folder.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri were you meaning run chmod 400 ~/.ssh/filename.pem -v?  If so, I'll run it again and post the results when I get back to that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an ssh folder in your home folder, if one is not present. Then copy the PEM file to that folder. Then change permissions of the PEM file to protect it. Something like this:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cp fred.pem.txt ~/.ssh/fred.pem
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/fred.pem
```

Comment: I did this, but to no avail.  I will try again when I get back to that computer and give you my feedback on it.  Like it mentions in the post, I believe there is a folder, I just can't see it and nothing I did to unhide it worked.  I don't recall the code I used off hand, but I can look it up and share it...but I do see that you are copying the file as a .txt.pem into the new ssh folder.  Does it matter if the extensions don't match and if the file is .pem.txt not .txt.pem?

Comment: The folder name begins with a dot. You cannot list it with ls. You need ls -a (the -a option includes directory entries whose names begin with a dot). If you're using Finder, then it's probably not visible by default. I have corrected the example I gave to show fred.pem.txt, but it really doesn't matter what the filename is, as long as it's actually a PEM file.

Comment: Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229846/connecting-to-amazon-aws-linux-server-by-ssh-on-mac

Comment: I did last night and tried that method, but again no-go.  That's why I'm befuddled.  Usually, I can find something here or on google, or figure it out on my own, but this is a bit of new territory for me and I can't seem to get it to work.  I'll retry this one again also.  Thanks for the help.  I'll post everything I find out/whatever comes up from the debugging if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please be sure to provide specific details of what you try and what the result is. Saying "it doesn't work", for example, is vague and will make it difficult to help you effectively. Be sure to provide specific error messages, for example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: mkdir -p ~/.ssh returns: /Users/<my last name>/.ssh: Not a directory

Comment: mkdir -p ~/.ssh returns ::  _mkdir: /Users/<last name>/.ssh: Not a directory_
chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/MyKeyPair.pem.txt returns :: _chmod: /Users/Aberly/.ssh/MyKeyPair.pem.txt: Not a directory_

Comment: I am guessing that you have incorrectly copied a file to ~/.ssh when there was no ~/.ssh folder so now you have a file called ~/.ssh when you should have a folder instead. If so then delete the file, then restart the instructions from mkdir -p ~/.ssh.

Comment: So, it appears that there was an executable Unix file saved as .ssh.  I deleted this and the code worked...obviously with a few modifications.   Thanks @Jarmod